# EF6 - How to determine principal/dependent sides from a NavigationProperty

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm putting together a process that consumes a compiled assembly, looks for a `DbContext`, and writes code-first files for the `context` and the various entity classes. It's part of a [larger project](https://github.com/msawczyn/EFDesigner).

Things are going fine, but I'm running into a wall trying to discover, for associations, which end is the principal and which the dependent. This is only an issue in 0-1..0-1 and 1..1 cardinalities, since the others can be determined based on the multiplicity of each end.

In these two cases, though, it's clear that EF6 knows which is which since they must be declared in the source. For example:

```
public class FooMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Foo>
{
   public FooMap()
   {
      HasKey(t => t.Id);
      ToTable("Foos");
      HasRequired(t => t.BarObj).WithRequiredPrincipal(t => t.FooObj);
   }
}
```

I'm starting with either a CSpace or OSpace `EntityType` (in that order, depending on which one's not null) and getting its `DeclaredNavigationProperties` property to cycle through the associations.

What do I look for to find the principal/dependent designations? Can't use `GetDependentProperties()` to see if it returns empty because it will return empty both if the `DeclaringType` is the principal and also if there aren't any user-defined foreign key properties (i.e., all shadow properties for FKs).

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that was the shortest run of any question I've posted to date :-)

After a flash of insight and some digging with dotPeek, I believe I have the answers I was looking for.

Starting with a `NavigationProperty` object:

```
   AssociationType associationType = (AssociationType) navigationProperty.RelationshipType;
   ReferentialConstraint constraint = associationType.Constraint;
   AssociationEndMember principalEnd = (AssociationEndMember) constraint.FromRole;
   AssociationEndMember dependentEnd = (AssociationEndMember) constraint.ToRole;
   EntityType principalType = principalEnd.GetEntityType();
   EntityType dependentType = dependentEnd.GetEntityType();
```

Note that this can, of course, be tightened up, but I figured I'd post it spread apart for educational purposes.