# Find Principal end and Dependent end out of EDM model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, edmx

I need to find all foreign keys using EDM model. I was able to pull many useful information using Systm.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata classes and methods but still not able to get Principal and Dependent from an association or relationship.
`ReferentialConstraint` class has public properties `FromRole`/`ToRole`, one of them is Principal and another is Dependent but I'm not sure which ones exactly.
`ReferentialConstraint` has private fields `PrincipalEnd` and `DependentEnd` who might help me but I woudn't like to access them via reflection. Is there a better way to figure out what end is Principal and what end is Dependent?

PS: I saw solution in this [EF6 - How to determine principal/dependent sides from a NavigationProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59545630/ef6-how-to-determine-principal-dependent-sides-from-a-navigationproperty) question but there is no proof it's 100% correct.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally found source code [here](https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/blob/main/src/EntityFramework/Core/Metadata/Edm/ReferentialConstraint.cs)

```
internal AssociationEndMember PrincipalEnd
{
    get { return (AssociationEndMember)FromRole; }
}

internal AssociationEndMember DependentEnd
{
    get { return (AssociationEndMember)ToRole; }
}
```